# Inheritance java "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, inheritance

We discussed about inheritance in java this morning but it seems that I have an error in my code and my professor could not help me because he is busy, can you just help my to point my error?

```
package inheritance;

class Inheritance {

  void accelerate()
  {
    System.out.println("Drive");
  }

  void turn()
  {
    System.out.println("Turn!");
  }
}


class n2wheels extends Inheritance {


  void fast()
  {
    System.out.println("Swift Vehicle");
  }

}


class n4wheels extends Inheritance {


  void normal()
  {
    System.out.println("Average Vehicle");
  }


}


class multiwheel extends Inheritance {


  void slow()
  {
    System.out.println("Heavy Vehicle");


  }


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Inheritance try1 = new Inheritance();
    try1.normal();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a method called `normal` in your class called `Inheritance`.

Comment: `normal` is no method of `Inheritance`.

Comment: Just a hint: There are tons of explanation about the inheritance in Java. Take a look on those and try to understand what it means and how it works. Otherwise you will have a lot of problems in the future because you obviously missunderstood something there. Good luck!

Comment: I was trying to call void normal, but it seem that i could not call it because obviously, something is wrong with my code. As a beginner in java, I really like to learn. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

there is no `normal` method in your `Inheritance` class.

do at least:

```
class Inheritance {

    void accelerate() {
        System.out.println("Drive");
    }

    void turn() {
        System.out.println("Turn!");
    }

    void normal(){}
}
```

or:

```
n4wheels try1 = new n4wheels();
try1.normal();
```

as a side node: please start class names uppercase. `N4Wheels`, `MultiWheels` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Normal() method does not exists in Inheritance class

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to call this method because it doesn't exist in Inheritance  class and present in n4wheels class. I don't know what you are trying to achieve so I am providing you possible solutions below.

**Solution 1:** If you want to call normal() in Inheritance class only then declare it in the same class.

```
class Inheritance {

  void accelerate() {
    System.out.println("Drive");
  }

  void turn() {
    System.out.println("Turn!");
  }

  void normal() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:** If you want to call normal() method of n4wheels class directly then:

```
n4wheels try1 = new n4wheels();
try1.normal();
```

**Solution 3:** If you want to perform polymorphism then, you have to declare normal() method in Inheritance class as mentioned in 'solution 1' and then,

```
Inheritance try1 = new n4wheels();
try1.normal();
```